# Xcode “Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64”

Tags: c++, xcode

This is the first experience with programming and I'm experiencing some problems with creating a library. The moment I run the problem, the following appears with the word:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "stampa(int const*, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now I am attaching here the written algorithm with the hope of receiving help.

File `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libarray.h"
#define N 5
using namespace std;
int main (){

    int v[N]={0};
    int R=0;

    stampa (v, R);

    system("pause");
    return 0; }
```

File `library.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "libarray.h"

using namespace std;

void stampa (int v[], int R) {
    do{
       cout << "Inserire riempimento: ";
       cin >> R;
    }while ( R>N );

    cout << "\nInserire elementi:\n";
    for ( int i=0; i<R; i++){
        cout << " - elemento indice " << i << ": ";
        cin >> v[i];
    } }
```

File `libarray.h`:

```
#define N 5

void stampa (const int v[], int R);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that you are declaring in `libarray.h` takes a `const int v[]` as first parameter.

The one you are defining in `library.cpp` takes a `int v[]` as first parameter.

These are not the same types and therefore not the same function overloads. You are never defining the function from the header and the error message is telling you that.

The definition of the version with `const` is needed because this is the one used for the call `stampa (v, R);` as it is the only overload of `stampa` that has been declared at that point in `main.cpp`.

Be consistent and use the same types in both declaration and definition of the function in both header and implementation file. Since you intend to modify elements of `v`, it can not be `const`. Therefore, in the header file, change

```
void stampa (const int v[], int R);
```

to

```
void stampa (int v[], int R);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now the problem is solved and the algorithm run without problem.

Answer (score -1):

It is a link error. I mean you haven't included library.cpp in the project settings.

Right-click on the project in the top-left and select Add files to “…”.